# how to use Background Worker in WPF C# in a switch

Tags: c#, wpf, switch-statement, backgroundworker

How can I able to use Background Worker in several times with different Dowork one at a time after one process to another process?

I have this code:

```
foreach (string item in Processes)
{
    ItemValue = item;
    //Get process code for the process under the selected source
    GetActiveProcess();

    switch (ProcessCode)
    {
        case "Download File":
            GetStartTime();
            UpdateDownloadStartTime();

            if (worker.IsBusy != true)
            {
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWorkDownload);
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            break;

        case "Unzip File":
            GetStartTime();
            UpdateDownloadStartTime();

            if (worker.IsBusy != true)
            {
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWorkUnzip);
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            break;

    }

}
```

Here is my code for DoWork and RunworkerCompleted

```
private void worker_DoWorkDownload(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DownloadFile();
}
private void worker_DoWorkUnzip(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ExtractFile();
}
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    GetEndTime();
    GetDuration();
    UpdateDownloadEndTime();
}
```

As for my code, it continues performing the Dowork at the same time. What I'm wanna do is to perform Backgroundworker for every item in my Process.

How can I do that?

Comment: One problem I see with the above code is that, if the worker is busy, you don't process the item.

Comment: I've move all my methods inside dowork and it do the trick. Although I uses dispatchertimer to refresh my grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your switch to DoWork handler and call DownloadFile or other in if block instead of subscribing and starting backgroundworker.

Comment: But In this code, Datagrid must refresh before doing the Downloadfile(). If I put the swith inside my Dowork, How can I possibly refresh my grid everytime each cases are done?

Comment: I've put my switch in my DoWork but I got this error saying that The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. **This error appeared in refreshing my datagrid. under **dataGridDownload.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

Comment: @KuriyamaMirai, dataGridDownload.Invoke((Action)()=>dataGridDownload.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView);

Comment: @ IL_Agent,I've tried your comment and it do work. It's better than using dispatchertimer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not switch to async/await instead?

```
foreach (string item in Processes)
{
  ItemValue = item;
  //Get process code for the process under the selected source
  GetActiveProcess();

  GetStartTime();
  UpdateDownloadStartTime();

  switch (ProcessCode)
  {
    case "Download File":
      await Task.Run(DownloadFile);
      break;

    case "Unzip File":
      await Task.Run(ExtractFile);
      break;
  }

  GetEndTime();
  GetDuration();
  UpdateDownloadEndTime();
}
```

Comment: I've put my switch in my DoWork but I got this error saying that **The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. **This error appeared in refreshing my datagrid. under  **dataGridDownload.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;**

Comment: You cannot update GUI controls in a background thread. GUI controls are only accessible on the main thread.

Comment: @KuriyamaMirai, dataGridDownload.Invoke((Action)()=>dataGridDownload.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView);

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to run these background workers in a non-concurrent manner, you need to wait until the first background do work function is finished before you can start the next do work function.

This means that you need to remove items off your Processes list differently. Remove the first item as you have, setup your worker and run the doWork, but then each subsequent item should be removed and the worker should be setup in the completed handler (worker_RunWorkerCompleted)

Also, you keep adding do work event handlers to your worker, without ever removing them.
And, you only need to add the worker_RunWorkerCompleted handler to the worker once - don't do it for every item you are processing.